# Polymer 3: Text to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, lit-html

In my Polymer page I get a text from db in a variable and the text contains HTML tags. How can I change this text to HTML formated? The text I get is something like following:

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>More text......</p>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Read more</a>
```

I display it in my page like the following, where `item.content` has the above text:

```
<div>
  <p>${item.content}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unsafeHTML` function from `lit-html` lib. See API reference [here](https://polymer.github.io/lit-html/api/modules/_lib_unsafe_html_.html).

Example:

```
import { unsafeHTML } from 'lit-html/directives/unsafe-html.js'

...

_render ({ yourHtmlString }) {
  return html`
    ${unsafeHTML(yourHtmlString)}
  `
}
```

Live demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-uxdalr?file=index.js).

Comment: Just a simple question? How can give innerHTML to my p tag here?

Comment: You can use normal `querySelector` and `innerHTML` after it render (inside `_didRender`). I have update the demo, you can see how to do it.